# How to change permissions on ftp file in rebol?

Tags: rebol

What's the function's name to change this permission on ftp file (ftp software can do it so I guess Rebol can too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTP has two ports open, one for commands and one for data transfer.  Since you only want to issue a command, then you don't need to use ftp, but can use the telnet protocol.

The ftp protocol in Rebol2 does not support site specific commands such as chmod.  However, I have written my own ftp protocol for Rebol3, ( see http://github.com/gchiu/Rebol3/tree/master/protocols/ ), and it looks like it is only a few lines to add the SITE command.

Comment: I'm still using rebol 2, why this would be specific to R3 ?

Comment: Rebol3 uses a completely different async port model from Rebol2 so the protocols are written differently.  Actually the protocols for Rebol3 have not been officially released/written either but I think mine should support chmod using the SITE command.  But since the question is how to change the permissions using Rebol, the answer for Rebol2 is to use the telnet scheme.

Comment: I agree will use telnet protocol with R2.

Answer (score 1):

The REBOL function for changing file permissions is `set-modes`.

However, that is enabled only for local files -- so no equivalent of `chmod` for remote files using FTP.

This thread suggests it may be possible to modify REBOL's `FTP scheme` to make it possible....
http://www.rebol.org/ml-display-thread.r?m=rmlSWGQ
....But, as far as I know, no one has.

Comment: I doubt I'm good enough to understand ftp scheme in rebol or I would try to do it so I have to wait for R3 release and use it with graham lib. Currently R3 seems not to work on my pc.

Comment: Does not work in what way?  It is really only working for Windows 32 bit ( not tried under 64 bit ).

Comment: Don't remember it was a long time ago must try again but I'm not interested to use it as it's not release and I have a bunch of r2 scripts already I don't want to lose time testing them.